# wmic delete startup item

Tags: wmic

I want to delete an entry with wmic but i always get an error, i saw DELETE command is a valid verb of STARTUP. what i am doing wrong?
thnx

```
wmic:root\cli>/node:'pc-test' startup where name="TwonkyServer" DELETE

Delete '\\pc-test\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_StartupCommand.Command="C:\\PROGRA~1\\Twonky\\TWONKY~1\\TWONKY~4.EXE ",Location="Common Startup",Name="TwonkyServer",User="Public"' (Y/N/?)? y
Deleting instance \\pc-test\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_StartupCommand.Command="C:\\PROGRA~1\\Twonky\\TWONKY~1\\TWONKY~4.EXE ",Location="Common Startup",Name="TwonkyServer",User="Public"
```

ERROR:
**Description = Provider is not capable of the attempted operation**

Comment: The WMIC `STARTUP` class is for informational purposes only. Use `REGISTRY` to delete a startup entry.

Comment: ok, but that is not in the registry is in CommonStartup folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can achieve it through WMI console, but through VBS try providing a priviliged moniker string in reference to the system:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389292(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You Can Get The Entry By This Command:

wmic startup get Location | findstr /B /C:"TwonkyServer"

Then Delete It From Registry

Reg delete  [{/v ValueName | /ve | /va}] [/f]

More Help At Reg Delete At:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742145.aspx